# Question about JavaFX Scene.lookup() method

Tags: java, performance, javafx, lookup

My question is that getting a Node using the method lookup(Selector) on a Scene Object or a Parent Object is a bad practice, considering i have some id for those nodes.

I'm talking about the search in the Node tree. Does it affect the performance greatly in a program? 
Should i save somewhere the references for the Nodes i want to get from the tree instead (just after i build the node tree)? The nodes height in the tree is at level 3, and some at level 4

P.S: I am building the node tree directly in the code, not using scene builder or other stuff.

Comment: I would avoid `lookup` whenever possible for at least three reasons: (1) It will be less efficient than keeping a reference to the needed `Node`; (2) You lose type safety since `lookup` returns `Node` and the compiler has no way of knowing what subtype is actually associated with the selector; (3) The code using `lookup` is likely to be less readable.

Comment: Also (4) Depending on the scene structure `lookup` won't work until a layout pass happens. E.g. `ScollPane.content` is added to the scene during a layout pass. Making logic depend on an additional state and/or the scene structure just adds an additional level of complexity/source of errors. If you can avoid that, it's preferrable to do so.

Comment: _Does it affect the performance greatly in a program_ what happened when you profiled your code? Anyway, what do you mean by _node tree_? Do you mean the visual representation of a TreeItem (wildly guessing  :)? If so, learn how to use TreeCell properly - if not, clarify what you want to achieve (with a [mcve])

Comment: With the node tree i am refering to a visual representation of the Scene and which type of nodes does every node contain. Like this: scene contains an AnchorPane root, then the root has 3 children: 1 Accordion, 1 TextArea and 1 Pane. After that, the accordion's got 3 titled panes, every titled pane having 2 children text inputs, and the pane inside root also got let's say 100 rectangle shapes inside. That's what i meant.

Comment: I am using lookup, because i have group of titledpanes in an accordion, that change depending on a ChoiceBox input (using changeListener), whose items are the number of titledpanes i want to appear there in the accordion.